# How to match similar routing conditions in a single path in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component named Details and the route for that looks like the following:

```
const appRoutes=[
  { path: "/details/:id", component: Details }
]
```

Now if the user tries to access only the "/details" route, I want to redirect them to an external URL, let's say "https://www.google.com". Currently I'm doing it by adding the following right after the line above in `appRoutes`.

```
`{ path: "/details", component: () => window.location.assign("https://www.google.com") }`
```

Is there a better way to do it in one line instead of two, so that I don't have to specify the case for `/details` and `details/:id` separately like I'm doing here? The expected behavior here is that if the route is `details/:id` then render the `Details` component and if it is just `details` then send them to an external URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of your idea, these are separate routes. So, it's for the best to use separate route statements to define them. If anything, this just makes your code more declarative and clear to other readers.

What I would recommend is to to pass `exact: true` to the `"/details"` route and place that **before** your `"/details/:id"` route. React Router has an easier time deciding which route to show when your exact routes are defined before your parameter-based routes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the recommendation!